# Drupal Form Submit Handler Not Working, But Why?

Tags: drupal-7

Why is my submit handler not being called when my form submits? The following function is called from a page template ... in a bootstrap modal window ... so a modal loads when the page loads. I have a feeling the conditions are interfering with the submit handler being called or I'm not returning something? This code is in a module for a form. I'm using the default submit handler.

```
function winner_modal_form_communication($node) {

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
```

I test to see if it's already been posted, otherwise two dates are subtracted from a field since it would be called twice (once on load and then once on post). If it's already been posted (since that would mean they filled out a winning form), I print out a confirmation message.

```
        // WINNING DATES

        if (!empty($node->field_win_dates{'und'}{0}{'value'})) {

            $winDatesString = $node->field_win_dates{'und'}{0}{'value'};

            $winDatesArray = explode(", ", $winDatesString);                        

        }

        // TODAYS DATE

        $todaysDatePST = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                                       


        // EVENT DATES

        $eventDateUTC = $node->field_date{'und'}{0}{'value'};                       

        $eventDateObject = new DateTime($eventDateUTC, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));    

        $eventDateObject->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));     

        $eventDatePST = $eventDateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I'm just setting up some variables ... and then some conditions.

```
        // EXPIRED EVENT

        if ($todaysDatePST > $eventDatePST) {

            print "Sorry, this event has expired.<br /><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Continue</button>";

        }

        // WINNER

        else if (($todaysDatePST > $winDatesArray[0]) && (!empty($winDatesString)))  {


            print "You've just won<br />TWO FREE TICKETS<br />to see " . $node->title . "!";


            $form = drupal_get_form('winner_modal_form');


            print drupal_render($form);


            unset($winDatesArray[0]);                                                       


            $newWinningDatesString = implode(", ",$winDatesArray);                           


            $node->field_win_dates{'und'}{0}{'value'} = $newWinningDatesString;             


            node_save($node);


        }


        // NO WINNER

        else {

            print "You didn't win tickets to " . $node->title. ", but you can still learn more by pressing the continue button.";

            print "<br /><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Continue</button>";


        }


    }


    // WINNER CONFIRMATION 

    else {


        print "Thank you! This is the confirmation modal window. That's right, you were the winner!<br /><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Continue</button>"; 


    }


}
```

If I remove the aforementioned conditions the submit handler works.

```
function winner_modal_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    dpm("It worked!");

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any insight would be greatly appreciated (I'm new to programming).

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets instead of curly brackets. Ex: $node->field_win_dates['und'][0]['value'].

Answer (score 0):

When in Drupal, do as  [Drupal asks](https://www.drupal.org/node/717740).

If you need to get data from a form, just use the *_validate and *_submit functions.

No need to handle the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].